# postgresql-simple query error

Tags: postgresql, haskell, postgresql-simple

EDIT: I now have a better idea of what is going wrong. When I perform that query in plain old `psql`, I get the following result:

```
lwm@verbos
=# SELECT * FROM gerund LIMIT1;                 
  infinitive │   gerund    │ gerund_english 
 ────────────┼─────────────┼────────────────
  abandonar  │ abandonando │ abandoning
```

So, I am getting back 3 strings? However, I say that I am getting back `IO [Only String]`. I am sure it is my type signature here that is messing things up ...

I am trying to make a simple query using the `postgresql-simple` library with `Haskell`. My code is pasted below along with the error I am seeing. Anyone got any ideas?

My database is called `verbos` and within it, I have a table called `gerund`. I am able to run a `query_` that contains: `conn "SELECT 2 + 2"` and that works fine. I can also connect to my database with the default data as specified with the default information (password = 'postgres' : `psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres` (from the docs[[1](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-simple-0.4.7.0/docs/Database-PostgreSQL-Simple.html#t:ConnectInfo)])

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Main where

import Control.Monad
import Control.Applicative
import Database.PostgreSQL.Simple

main = do
    conn <- connect defaultConnectInfo {
        connectPassword = "postgres",
        connectDatabase = "verbos"
    }
    mapM_ print =<< (query_ conn "SELECT * FROM gerund LIMIT 1" :: IO [Only String])
```

Gives me the following error:

> ConversionFailed {errSQLType = "3 values: [(Basic {typoid = Oid 1043,
>   typcategory = 'S', typdelim = ',', typname = \"varchar\"},Just
>   \"abandonar\"),(Basic {typoid = Oid 1043, typcategory = 'S', typdelim
>   = ',', typname = \"varchar\"},Just \"abandonando\"),(Basic {typoid = Oid 1043, typcategory = 'S', typdelim = ',', typname =
>   \"varchar\"},Just \"abandoning\")]", errSQLTableOid = Nothing,
>   errSQLField = "", errHaskellType = "1 slots in target type",
>   errMessage = "mismatch between number of columns to convert and number
>   in target type"}

Comment: I don't know any Haskell but it seems to be complaining that you're trying to treat the `infinite` column (a `varchar` in the database) as an integer and Haskell doesn't like that.

Comment: Hey, this led me to the fact I am declaring the return type of the Query to be a 'Int' but it really is a string ... I got a new error now ... updating the question ...

Comment: But wouldn't the return from `select *` be a list or array of some sort? The `"mismatch between number of columns to convert and number in target type"` error is suggestive, no? Do you really want `select * `? Maybe you want `select some_column_name` instead. I still don't know any Haskell, just making some guesses.

Comment: Yes, that's it. Without the structure of the table we can't confirm, but most likely your table has several columns, and you're trying to squeeze them all into a single value of type String. That won't work. Either select a single column or define a Haskell type (and the appropriate `FromRow` instance) that has enough room for the 3 columns of your table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, Thanks to @AlpMestanogullari, @muistooshort, I got an answer here. My final code is:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Main where

import Control.Applicative
import Database.PostgreSQL.Simple
import Database.PostgreSQL.Simple.FromRow

data Gerund = Gerund { 
    f :: String, 
    s :: String, 
    t :: String 
} deriving (Show)

instance FromRow Gerund where 
    fromRow = Gerund <$> field <*> field <*> field

main = do
    conn <- connect defaultConnectInfo {
        connectPassword = "postgres",
        connectDatabase = "verbos"
    }
    mapM_ print =<< (query_ conn q :: IO [Gerund])
        where q = "SELECT * FROM gerund LIMIT 1"
```

Notes:

- Knowing that my result contained 3 result columns, I needed to define a `type` that had 'space' for the results (`f`, `s` and `t` in the `Gerund` type)
- I followed the docs[[1](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-simple-0.4.8.0/docs/Database-PostgreSQL-Simple.html#t:FromRow)] for FromRow closely to get my `type` and `instance` defined.
- You need to import `import Database.PostgreSQL.Simple.FromRow` to access things like `field`.