# Using postgres-simple, how do I get multiple parameters from a row

Tags: postgresql, haskell

I am trying to make a fairly basic query with postgresql-simple 0.5.0.1 and with 0.5.1.0. I am already familiar with the content in [postgresql-simple query error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26952685/postgresql-simple-query-error), but I get a different error message.

```
data SensorRow = SensorRow Int String String deriving Show
instance FromRow SensorRow where
    fromRow = SensorRow <$> field <*> field <*> field

*DatabaseIntegrationSpec> db <- connectPostgreSQL dbString 
*DatabaseIntegrationSpec> r <- query_ db "SELECT (id, name, token) FROM sensor" :: IO [SensorRow]
*** Exception: Incompatible {errSQLType = "record", errSQLTableOid = Nothing, errSQLField = "row", errHaskellType = "Int", errMessage = "types incompatible"}
*DatabaseIntegrationSpec> r <- query_ db "SELECT (id, name, token) FROM sensor" :: IO [(Int, String, String)]
*** Exception: Incompatible {errSQLType = "record", errSQLTableOid = Nothing, errSQLField = "row", errHaskellType = "Int", errMessage = "types incompatible"}
*DatabaseIntegrationSpec>
```

By my reading of the documentation and all of the example code, both of these queries should work. However, reading the error message, especially `errSQLField`, it appears in both cases that the library is trying to convert the *entire row* into an int.

So, what is wrong here? Have I encountered a bug in the postgresql-simple library, and if so, how can I work around it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entire problem ultimately lay in my SQL query. The correct query to use is:

```
*DatabaseIntegrationSpec> r <- query_ db "SELECT id, name, token FROM sensor" :: IO [SensorRow]
```

In short, putting parenthesis around the field names in the query causes PostgreSQL to return things in a format I do not know how to decode.